# Using Requisites in Reactor Files

Tags: salt-stack

How do I use requisites in reactor files?

I only want to run the second state if the first completes successfully.

```
{% if ('id' in data) and ('act' in data) and ('pub' in data) and
            ((data['act'] == 'pend') and (data['pub'] != '')) %}
check_minion_domain_joined:
  local.cmd.run:
    - tgt: 'MINIONNAME'
    - arg:
        - powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:/salt/auth-minion.ps1" {{ data['id'] }}

accept_key_domain_joined:
  wheel.key.accept:
    - match: {{ data['id'] }}
    - require:
      - cmd: check_minion_domain_joined
{% endif %}
```

I can see that the first state is being run by the master via the output of `salt-run state.event`, but "accept_key_domain_joined" never runs.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/), reactor SLS files do not support requisites.

> Reactor SLS files, by design, do not support requisites, ordering, onlyif/unless conditionals and most other powerful constructs from Salt's State system.

The better option is to trigger orchestration from the reactor. So instead of having the two actions performed from reactor, just call for an orchestration run:

Example `reactor/file.sls`:

```yaml
create-file-with-content:
  runner.state.orch:
  - args:
    - mods: orch.create_file
    - pillar:
        min_id: {{ data['id'] }}
        min_act: {{ data['act'] }}
```

Then in `orch/create_file.sls`, we can use the pillar data and accomplish the tasks.

Example:

```yaml
{% set minion_id = salt.pillar.get('min_id') %}
{% set minion_act = salt.pillar.get('min_act') %}

touch-a-tmp-file:
  salt.function:
  - name: file.touch
  - tgt: {{ minion_id }}
  - arg:
    - /tmp/dummy.file

update-tmp-file:
  salt.function:
  - name: file.append
    tgt: {{ minion_id }}
    arg:
    - /tmp/dummy.file
    - minion_act is {{ minion_act }}
  - require:
    - salt: touch-a-tmp-file
```

There is some more information on troubleshooting pillar information in reactor-orchestration states [here](https://help.saltstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041041351-Troubleshooting-pillar-information-in-reactor-orchestration-states).